# Django prefetch_related nested models

Tags: python, django, database, prefetch

I want to do a 3 lvl prefetch_related but I can't make it work.

**views.py:**

```
queryset = obj.answer.all().prefetch_related(Prefetch('question ', queryset=Question.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('orderedquestion', queryset=OrderedQuestion.objects.prefetch_related('select_set')))))

return AnswerSerializer(queryset, many=True).data
```

And on my **Serializers.py** I call it like that:

```
json['name'] = answer.question.orderedquestion.select_set.get(id=i).name
```

I don't know if this metters but my OrderedQuestion class inherits from Question.

My **Models.py**

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    updated_datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='answer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='answer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = JSONField(blank=True, null=True)

class Question(models.Model):
    objects = InheritanceManager()
    title_question = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=True)
    title_interest = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    description_question = models.CharField(max_length=2048, null=True, blank=True)
    description_interest = models.CharField(max_length=2048, null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    
class OrderedQuestion(Question):
    multiple_choice = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    dont_care = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Select(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    choice_question = models.ForeignKey(ChoiceQuestion, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    ordered_question = models.ForeignKey(OrderedQuestion, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + ' - ' + self.name
```

How can I fetch select_set on the first query so my serializer stop doing N queries for each object?

Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Just for clarity: Can youm share models in question?

Comment: Please add models to the question and also tell us about the end goal you want to achieve. May there is another better way to achieve it.

Comment: Thanks guys , I've just added the Models.py on the question. 

My end goal is to prefetch all data on the views.py - get_queryset() to the serializers.py. The simple ones I manage to do but this nested one is hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code should work. I wrote year ago similar solution for real state agency and it looks like that:

```py
OfferType.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('offer_type_biurowin', queryset=OfferTypeBiurowin.objects.prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('offers', queryset=Offer.objects.select_related('locality').prefetch_related(
            Prefetch('gallery', to_attr='gallery_list')), to_attr='offer_list')
), to_attr='biurowin_list')
```

Debugging with `django-debug-toolbar` package is showing that this code does only 3 queries. The 3 queries are must, because this is way how SQL works - it contains 3 different tables, it can't fetch data from multiple tables using one query, but it's probably better than 100+ queries without using `.prefetch_related()` or `.select_related()`.

You can check if your code works using mentioned `django-debug-toolbar` or by using `django-silk`.

@EDIT:
Sorry, I was dumb - just noticed that you are using this line:

```py
json['name'] = answer.question.orderedquestion.select_set.get(id=i).name
```

You can't fetch question by using direct-attribute call, you must do something like this:

```py
answer.question_set.first().orderedquestion_set.first().select_set_set.get(id=i).name
```

The `many-to-many` and `reverse-fk` relations contains MULTIPLE objects. You can't fetch just single question without using `.first()` or calling first element by:

```py
answer.question_list[0]
```

(If you use `to_attr` attribute in prefetch).

Also, if you use direct `models.ForeignKey` call, you should use `select_related()`, not `prefetch_related()`.

Comment: Thank you @Patryk

Acctually the problem was related with the inherited classes 

This just dont work

`obj.answer.all().prefetch_related(Prefetch('question ', queryset=Question.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('orderedquestion', queryset=OrderedQuestion.objects.prefetch_related('select_set')))))`

Because my OrderedQuestion inherits from Question

But this works

`prefetch_related(Prefetch('question__interest', queryset=Interest.objects.filter(profile=me).prefetch_related(Prefetch('selects', queryset=Select.objects.all(), to_attr='interestselects')), to_attr='myinterest'))`